# SwiftData: how to add constraints?

Tags: swift, swift-data

Does [SwiftData](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/swiftdata/) support constraints, such as a number of minimum/maximum string etc.

I couldn't find a document for this.

Comment: No there are no such constraints currently and maybe there never will be in the same way as Core Data had since we are now implementing our models using swift code so any such constraints might need to be implemented by us as well. I guess we will have to wait and see what happens.